# Why is React Native Versioning looking for a "pre" folder?

Tags: react-native, fastlane, yarn-v2

What am I missing if I want to do automatic sync of ios and android builds for version / build #.

I'm trying to use npm version

```
npm version patch --no-git-tag-version && bundle exec fastlane bump

> preversion
> react-native-version pre

[RNV] Cannot find module '/Projects/ReactNative/SimpleParamPassing/pre/package.json'
```

where is it getting this "pre" folder from?

Comment: What's running `react-native-version pre`? Is it your fastlane script?

Comment: I'm using yarn with the following script

"bump-patch": "npm version patch --no-git-tag-version && bundle exec fastlane bump",